# Invalid keyring : Are Hadoop gpg KEYS are wrong?

Tags: docker, hadoop, gnupg

I am using debian:9 image and doing the following

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      openjdk-8-jdk \
      net-tools \
      curl \
      netcat \
      gnupg \
      vim \
      wget \
      unzip

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/

RUN curl -O https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/hadoop/common/KEYS

RUN gpg --import KEYS
```

It fails with

```
gpg: invalid armor header: mQINBF9U5ZcBEADJS2a8ihhZtN1wXOJfyLZreuHL9HJxRvogQbhrhpFQrKAusdf2\n
gpg: CRC error; 95D523 - 51AC03
gpg: packet(7) with unknown version 103
gpg: read_block: read error: Invalid packet
gpg: import from 'KEYS' failed: Invalid keyring
gpg: Total number processed: 60
gpg:               imported: 60
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
****
```

I am not sure what is wrong. I am on mac and upon building the image I get this error. Does this mean the Hadoop KEYS are wrong and outdated?
Is it because of debian:9 image?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a malformed key entry in the current KEYS file. Make sure that there are new line characters between `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----` and the actual keys.

For me, in the current KEYS file there is a newline missing after line 5520:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
mQINBF9U5ZcBEADJS2a8ihhZtN1wXOJfyLZreuHL9HJxRvogQbhrhpFQrKAusdf2
...
```

which should be:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

mQINBF9U5ZcBEADJS2a8ihhZtN1wXOJfyLZreuHL9HJxRvogQbhrhpFQrKAusdf2
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, I will give it a try. But it's part of the Hadoop's apache dist.

Comment: Yes, it is. Probably someone has to report this.

Comment: Here is a link to the created ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17364